# Equation of an ellipsoid based on vectors and norms

Tags: convex-optimization, conic-sections, convex-geometry

Boyd's 'Convex Optimization' states that ellipsoids have the form,

$(x-x_c)^TP^{-1}(x-x_c)\leq 1 $;  Equation (1)

where P is a symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix and $x_c$ is the centre of the ellipse. This part is clear enough.

It also states that the ellipsoid can also be written in the form,

$ x_c + Au \quad ||u||_2\leq1$;   Equation (2)

where A is square and nonsingular.

However the book then states that by taking $A=P^{1/2}$, Equation(2) can be described in the form of Equation(1). How did they come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\{x | (x-x_c)^T P^{-1} (x-x_c) \le 1 \} &=& \{x_c\}+ \{x | x^TP^{-1} x \le 1 \} \\
&=& \{x_c\}+ \{x |\| P^{- {1 \over 2}} x\|  \le 1 \} \\
&=& \{x_c\}+ \{P^{{1 \over 2}}x | \ \|  x\|  \le 1 \} \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: How did you go from $||P^{-1/2}x||$ to $P^{1/2}x$ outside the norm in the last step? Why is there no -ve sign for $P^{1/2}$? Is it some property of norms?

Comment: $P^{-{1 \over 2}} x \in \bar{B}(0,1)$ **iff** $x \in P^{{1 \over 2}} \bar{B}(0,1)$

Comment: It is just variable substitution. In the second last line, let $y = P^{-{1 \over 2}} x$, then $x = P^{{1 \over 2}} y$.

Comment: Just another query. Is $A^{m}A^{n}=A^{m+n}$ true even if $m,n$ are fractions? Is it true for all reals? You seem to have used $P^{-1/2}P^{-1/2}=P^{-1}$

Comment: If $P$ is positive semidefinite we can define a square root that satisfies the above (diagonalise and take square roots). Presumably that is what Stephen et al. did.